# Unlimitted entries in Watchdog table

Tags: log-messages

I need to set watchdog log entries to unlimitted. Now it clears every time when cron is called.

```
admin/settings/logging/dblog
```

now maximum is 100000, is there any better way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just change the setting to "ALL" that should work. Please see the screen below !

[image]

Cron will run only if minimum limit is set in the select box see the below code in dblog module.

```
function dblog_cron() {
  // Cleanup the watchdog table.
  $row_limit = variable_get('dblog_row_limit', 1000);

  // For row limit n, get the wid of the nth row in descending wid order.
  // Counting the most recent n rows avoids issues with wid number sequences,
  // e.g. auto_increment value > 1 or rows deleted directly from the table.
  if ($row_limit > 0) {
    $min_row = db_select('watchdog', 'w')
      ->fields('w', array('wid'))
      ->orderBy('wid', 'DESC')
      ->range($row_limit - 1, 1)
      ->execute()->fetchField();

    // Delete all table entries older than the nth row, if nth row was found.
    if ($min_row) {
      db_delete('watchdog')
        ->condition('wid', $min_row, '<')
        ->execute();
    }
  }
}
```

If we select value as "ALL" which is 0, Cron won't delete any entries !

For Drupal 6,

You can use [Elysia Cron](http://drupal.org/project/elysia_cron) module, to turn off the dblog_cron feature.

Elysia Cron Module tells,

> Turn off (disable) a cron task/feature you don't need.

Comment: Updated solution for D6 :-)

Answer (score 5):

Never flushing your Watchdog log via CRON or at least manually clearing the log every so often will eventually cause you problems.  If you are on a dedicated or virtual Linux host consider using [Syslog](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/syslog) instead of Watchdog for your Drupal logging (available in both Drupal 6 and 7.)

This will allow you to keep an unlimited and permanent log of your Drupal events.  The setup guide also shows you how to use logrotate so log files don't get out of hand.

This will likely have a huge impact on performance as well. This is due to being able to prevent the excessive DB writes that Watchdog initiates.

Excerpt from Drupal.org regarding the Syslog module

> **Install & configure the Syslog module**
>
> Go to the Modules page, /admin/build/modules, and install the Syslog
>   module. Then go to the Syslog settings page,
>   /admin/settings/logging/syslog (D6) or the Logging and errors
>   configuratiion page, admin/config/development/logging (D7), and select
>   which Syslog level to attach to the log messages. Choose one that is
>   not in use by Syslog
>
> **Configure Syslog to Log to a Separate File**
>
> Edit `/etc/syslog.conf` and add:
>
> ```
> local0.* /var/log/drupal.log
> ```
>
> (if local0 is the level that you configured Syslog to use in Step 1)
>
> Then, restart Syslog:
>
> ```
> service syslog restart
> ```
>
> Note that this is optional. If you do not do this, your messages will
>   most likely be in `/var/log/messages`.
>
> **Disable the Database Logging (formerly, Watchdog) Module**
>
> Check that you are seeing messages in the syslog by using
>
> ```
> tail /var/log/drupal.log
> ```
>
> You can also browse the file by using less.
>
> If it is working, you may now go to the modules page and disable
>   Dblog.

For complete entry, visit [Syslog: OS-integrated logging](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/syslog)

Comment: If you are going to use dblog (aka can't use syslog due to a shared environment or other BS), what do you think is a reasonable upper boundary for number of log entries?